# APIs Explorer's Firestore's projects.databases.documents.list has incorrect regex

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-apis-explorer

*Summary: [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) "Try this API" for [`projects.databases.documents.list`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/list) appears (!?) to have an overly restrictive/incorrect regex on `parent` and requirement on `collectionId`.*

Neither `gcloud firestore` nor `firebase firestore:` provides functionality to list collections, I'm planning to write a simple app to do so.

As always, I explored the APIs methods using the excellent [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) **but** the [`projects.databases.documents.list`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/list) "Try this API" appears (!?) to have an overly restrictive|incorrect regex on `parent`.

The documentation correctly states that:

`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*/databases/*/documents/*/**}/{collectionId}`

And:

Required. The parent resource name. In the format:
`projects/{project_id}/databases/{database_id}/documents` or
`projects/{project_id}/databases/{database_id}/documents/{document_path}`.
For example: `projects/my-project/databases/my-database/documents` or `projects/my-project/databases/my-database/documents/chatrooms/my-chatroom`

Using Google's first format example: `projects/my-project/databases/my-database/documents` does not work:

[image]

APIs Explorer only accepts the second format example for `parent` but then requires a value for `collectionId` which may not be desired:

[image]

APIs Explorer appends `collectionId` to the `parent` to from the URL. In the case of `parent` ending `/documents` (which isn't permitted), this would make sense to access the `chatrooms` collection or in the case that `parent` ends `/documents/chatrooms/my-chatroom` to then get the `messages` collection (with `my-chatroom`) but the requirement prohibits using APIs Explorer (!) to query `projects/my-project/databases/my-database/documents/chatrooms`; `collectionId` is required and would need to be `chatrooms` but a parent of `projects/my-project/databases/my-database/documents` is not permitted.

Using one of my projects (`${PROJECT}`) and `(default)` for `{database_id}`, I can use the documentation's examples correctly in curl:

```bash
TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)

PROJECT=...
PARENT=projects/${PROJECT}/databases/(default)/documents
COLLECTION=...

curl \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}"   \
--header 'Accept: application/json'   \
--write-out '%{response_code}' \
--output /dev/null \
--silent \
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/${PARENT}/${COLLECTION}

200
```

The APIs works correctly navigating down through subcollections too.

Posting this here in the hopes that, if APIs Explorer is indeed incorrect, fixing it can help other developers not encounter this issue and be discouraged.

*Note: Since I'm posting feedback, the tool doesn't correctly adjust `cURL`, `HTTP` or `JavaScript` generated examples to reflect the checkbox value on "API Key"; when the "API Key" is deselected, the parameter should **not** be included in the calls.*

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the regular expression in the API explorer. I need to enter the `parent` as `projects/fire-template-24/databases/(default)/documents/users/` (including the forward slash) and also enter the `collectionId` as it's required (`users` in my case). This seems to be making a query at:

```
https://[GOOGLE+APIS_URL]/projects/[ID]/databases/(default)/documents/users//users?key=[API_KEY]
```

This returns an error about the extra trailing slash which the API explorer forced me to add and `collectionId` field is also appended to it with another `/`.

The following regular expression seems to be working:

```
^projects\/[^/]+\/databases\/[^/]+\/documents(\/[^/]+(\/[^/]+\/[^/]+)*)$
```

The above RegEx doesn't required a forward slash in `parent` and matches a collection path only. If the `collectionId` is removed then it should work. Working example of the RegEx can be found [here](https://regexr.com/64ec5).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, your experience matches mine, thanks! I think it would make more sense if the parent were to path to the database and then, instead of `collectionId`, there were a path property that could reference some (sub)collection or document. Hopefully the aforementioned Google engineers are reading this too.

Comment: @DazWilkin yes, there's a feedback button at the bottom if the page. I'll try to post one in the morning. Maybe you can do post one too :)

Comment: That's for the documentation which is correct. APIs Explorer itself suggests posting here.

Answer (score 0):

I could also observe the same in the API explorer page. I observed that there is an [existing issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/170376899) in the Public Issue Tracker for the same. As mentioned in the [#2 comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170376899#comment2)  of the issue, this issue report has been forwarded to the Firestore Engineering team to investigate, but there is no ETA for a resolution. I would suggest you star the issue so that you will get notified whenever there is any update on the issue.